# session maintaning after user log in

Tags: ios, swift2, nsurlsession

I have working on the application with logging.
On login view user can write login and password and when he tap on "login" button this login and passwort is send to serwer by nsurlsession.
dataTaskWithRequest is opening session on serwer but shis session expires in a few minutes. But any action in application need comunication with the serwer.
So i need maintain session after user tap login button (or when app is open, when user is logged). How i can do this?
I now, serwer should return me some key to autenticate, but this does not...

Comment: This question needs better English and more detail.

Comment: Save the username/password in memory and if the server returns error 401 (unauthorized), re-create the session.

Comment: i have this, but in my opinion should exist better solution